# Do Flask/Jinja2 have a provision to save rendered templates during debugging?

Tags: emacs, flask, jinja2

While debugging it's useful to view the rendered HTML and JS templates through a "view source" menu item in a browser, but doing so forces one to use the UI of the browser.

Does Jinja2 (or Flask) provide a facility to save the last n rendered templates on the server? It would then be possible to use one's favorite editor to view the rendered files, along with using one's familiar font-locking and search facilities.

It's of course possible to implement such a facility by hand, but doing so smacks too much like peppering one's programs while debugging with print statements, an approach that doesn't scale. I'm seeking a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think the easiest thing to do would be to use the `after_request` hook.

```
from flask import g
@main.route('/')
def index():
    models = Model.query.all()
    g.template = 'index'
    return render_template('index.html', models=models)


@main.after_request
def store_template(response):
    if hasattr(g, 'template'):
        with open('debug/{0}-{1}'.format(datetime.now(), g.template), 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.data)
    return response
```

Here are the docs.
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/53/

As far as only collecting the last `n` templates I'd likely setup a cron job to do that. Here is an example

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def make_files(n):
    text = '''
    <html>
    </html>
    '''

    for a in range(n):
        with open('debug/index-{0}.html'.format(datetime.now()), 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)

def get_files(dir):
    return [file for file in os.listdir(dir) if file.endswith('.html')]

def delete_files(dir, files, amount_kept):
    rev = files[::-1]
    for file in rev[amount_kept:]:
        loc = dir + '/' + file
        os.remove(loc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_files(7)
    files = get_files('debug')
    print files
    delete_files('debug', files, 5)
    files = get_files('debug')
    print files
```

**EDIT**

reversed order of files inside the delete function so it will keep the most recent files. Also unable to find a way of accessing the original template name to avoid hardcoding.

**EDIT 2**

Alright so updated it to show how you can use `flask.g` to pass the template name to the `after_request` function

docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/testing/#faking-resources

Comment: Good question, good answer. The one change I'd recommend is use Python logging; then you have configurable control on how much logging, and you can use the RotatingFileHandler. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler

Comment: only problem is differentiating between templates. I'll try and figure that out.

Comment: When you create the loggers, you can give them names which will then help.

Comment: Ended up using `flask.g` because it only exists within the scope of one request cycle so it makes it perfect to pass the name of the template throughout the life cycle.

Comment: This is such a nice answer that I wish I didn't ask about purging the last n files. It's an orthogonal issue that could be done from the command line, within `@main.after_request def store_template(response)`, or even by hand. In the first part, setting `g.template` in every single view function is unattractive, and so I'm taking the liberty of modifying the first part for the case when I'm focusing my debugging on just one or a few view functions.

Comment: Whatever works for you! I've never thought of this as a use case for `after_request` so I am glad you asked it!